# Turn simple form checkbox into a toggle switch

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a few checkboxes inside a `simple_form_for`:

```
<%= f.input :agree, label: "Agree with terms and conditions*" %>
```

which outputs the following html:

```
<div class="form-group boolean optional enrollment_agree">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <input value="0" type="hidden" name="enrollment[agree]">
    <label><input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="enrollment[agree]" id="enrollment_agree"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I found a nice and simple material design toggle switch http://codepen.io/chrisota/pen/jWmqvx which works with the following html:

```
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" class="hide"/>
<label for="toggle"><span class="hide">Label Title</span></label>
```

How can I make it work within the rails form?

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field to your form and update the value of the hidden with javascript when the toggle occurs.

javascript:

```
$('#toggle').change(function(evt) {
   $('#hidden_field').value = $(this).value();
});
```

Comment: right, so basically stick with the plain html, and update agree attribute behind the curtains.

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  Use JS to set your form value on click.